# Mysql query in rails active record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How would I convert this Mysql query to be run by rails active record?

`SELECT * FROM opentimes WHERE id=1 AND open < NOW() AND closed > NOW();`

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`OpenTimes.where(id: 1)`
Assuming that you're following convention and ID is your primary key, you wouldn't need the second part of the query. Even then, here it is:
`OpenTimes.where(id: 1, 'open < NOW() AND closed > NOW()')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model name is OpenTime and columns are id, open and close.
The corresponding active record query for above sql will be:

```
OpenTime.where("entity_id = ? AND created_at < ? AND updated_at > ?", 1, Time.now, Time.now)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a scope in your Opentime model:

```
class Opentime < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  scope :currently_open, -> { where('NOW() BETWEEN open AND closed') }
  ...
end
```

then you would use it like this:

```
Opentime.currently_open.where(id: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord has [find_by_sql](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql) method, so it can be used simple as this:

```
Opentime.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM opentimes WHERE id=1 AND open < NOW() AND closed > NOW();")
```